# Python3&selenium raise Message: Can not connect to the Service geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to install selenium in my PC so I tried these:

```
    pip install selenium
```

Then I went to [this site](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) to download `geckodriver` and copied it to `/usr/bin` .

To test if selenium is working. I ran these code and got an error(after 30sec).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.python.org')
assert 'Python' in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
elem.send_keys('pycon')
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

[traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNBCA.png)

Any idea how to solve this? I searched some similar questions but didn't find a solution. I'd appriciate it if someone can provide some infomation.

```
OS:Ubuntu 16.04
Firefox:55
python:3.5
selenium:3.4
```

---

**Problem solved!** Thanks for your help guys.

**Solution**: make sure there is `127.0.0.1 localhost` in the file `/etc/host`

It turns out that I changed the file for fun a long time ago and forgot to change it back T_T. After I added the `127.0.0.1 localhost` , everything is fine.

Comment: Try moving the geckodriver to the folder where your python script is.

Comment: Great.. your solution helped me

Answer (score 1):

> Solution: make sure there is 127.0.0.1 localhost in the file /etc/host

It works for me perfectly!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30747944)

Comment: ok, I've got it

Comment: Can anyone explain why `127.0.0.1 localhost` lack in `/etc/hosts` has such an effect?

Answer (score 0):

Move the `geckodriver` to `/usr/local/bin`. You should avoid touching `/usr/bin`

Also add executable permission to the same

```
chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/geckodriver
```

Then in your terminal use `echo $PATH`. Make sure `/usr/local/bin` is a part of it. If it is not then execute below

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Then run your python script. And now it should be able to work

Comment: I tried experimenting with permissions but got a very specific traceback with "permissions denied" error there..not sure if this is what OP is actually experiencing.

Comment: I tried moving geckodrive to /usr/local/bin first. It's not working. Then I tried moving it to /usr/bin. Sadly, not woking. I am sure geckodrive is executable and both /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin is in the PATH

Comment: Which version of gecko driver and which version of Firefox?

Comment: Version and solution are added to the question. Thank you.