# How to fix: Can not connect to the Service Geckodriver For Mac in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, geckodriver

I've recently come across a new problem where I return to one of my webscrapers on my Mac. But after I've left the scraper alone for a month or so, has the scraper stopped working! Something might have gotten outdated, though I cannot find the cause. See codeblock below:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://google.com')
browser.quit()
```

With the error:

```py
  raise WebDriverException(f"Can not connect to the Service {self._path}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /Users/marcojohanssontornblom/.cache/selenium/geckodriver/mac64/0.34.0/geckodriver
```

After researching the problem I've found multiple articles covering the topic, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843575/python3selenium-raise-message-can-not-connect-to-the-service-geckodriver) one.

But none of which explaining a decent solution for us Macintosh users! Which becomes a problem since every step by step solution is written for Windows users. Any suggestions?

~ Your fellow webscraper

Comment: Did you [download `geckodriver`](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)? That was one of the first gotchas that I ran into when I started out with selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the wrong Geckodriver! There are two of them: the tar version and 64arcch, where I had downloaded the 64arcch one not knowing which one was the correct choice.

So anybody out there having the same issue, try downloading both versions before continuing to research the topic.